# Rails 7: ActionText doesn't work. A field of rich_text_area isn't clickable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, actiontext

A have an error in simple form with field 'rich_text_area'.

1. I typed command `rails action_text:install`.
2. And I added a migration for already existed Model:

```
class MigrateCommentBodyToActionText < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
  def change
    rename_column :comments, :body, :body_old
    Comment.all.each do |comment|
      comment.update_attribute(:body, simple_format(comment.body_old))
    end
    remove_column :comments, :body_old
  end
end
```

3. Added `@import 'actiontext'` in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss`
4. Added  `has_rich_text :body` in Comment's model.
5. My form looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for model, method: method do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :body, as: :rich_text_area, :label => t("comments.add_comments"), required: true %><br />
  <%= f.select :status, Comment::VALID_STATUES.collect{|status| status }, { selected: Comment::VALID_STATUES[0], class: "form-select form-select-sm", 'aria-label': ".form-select-sm example" } %><br /><br />
  <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-light" %>
  <%= link_to "Cancel", article_path(@article), class: "btn btn-light" if f.object.persisted? %>
<% end %>
```

A have an image of the field but I cant click on it and input any text. what I could make wrong?

[The image of the field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dmNt.jpg)

Comment: ActionText relies extensively on Javascript. Did you follow the [steps in the guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html#installation)? Have you tried any kind of actual problem solving like checking the browser console for errors and made sure Trix is present and working on the page?